# I can't figure out why this XML doesn't validate in my RSS feed

Tags: xml, rss, cdata

I'm trying to make this RSS feed work, but I'm getting a weird error I can't figure out. The error is:

```
XML parsing error: <unknown>:30:37: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

and the code that is triggering the error is:

```
    <description><![CDATA[For this weeks poll to poll, we want to know whether or not you think the new enrollment policy is a huge mistake. Vote after the jump.
How do you feel about the new enrollment policy at Toms?]]></description>
```

This code takes up two lines, the second line beginning at "How do you feel" and the error is listed as occurring on the first line (starting with "for this weeks poll to poll" and ending at "jump.")

I can't figure out where the error is and any help would be awesome. Thanks,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the XML, but looks like the line feed is causing your parser issues. What parser are you using?